# GCC vtable issue with boost libraries

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I am having an issue compiling my program here are my gcc options used

```
g++ -shared -fPIC -fvisibility -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/  -lboost_serialization-mt -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_date_time-mt -lboost_iostreams-mt -lboost_program_options-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_system-mt
```

output

```
relocation R_X86_64_32S against `vtable for boost::detail::sp_counted_base' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

could not read symbols: Bad value
```

Does anyone know why this is happening ? thanks

Comment: error is quite clear, you need to recompile boost  with `-fPIC` flag. Or don't use this flag for your program.

Comment: I have compiled the whole program with these flags

Comment: read my comment carefully, did you compile **boost** with this flag?

Comment: sorry I just apt-get install libboost so I do not know what it was compiled with

Comment: that's the problem then, you need to get boost sources and recomplie them with `-fPIC` flag. But make sure you REALLY need it, bcecause compiling boost is not for fainthearted

Comment: @gda2004, can you provide some minimal test case? The system's Boost shared libraries ought to be properly compiled with `-fPIC`.

Comment: @chill not at the moment I am trying to isolate it the problem. I will get back to you if I find anything out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the boost library using `apt-get install libboost`

If you have any issues installing libboost, refer [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87306/how-to-install-libboost-1-48) in order to get them clarified.
After doing this, you can recompile boost with -fPIC flag in order to resolve the issue. I think the warning itself is helpful to identify your issue.

Comment: it installed just fine with libboost-dev It turned out that somewhere a friend had not included -fPIC

Comment: @gda2004 - So, I hope that you would have resolved the issue by including `-fPIC`